# Ring homomorphisms between $C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ and $C(\text{Cantor set},\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, continuity, cantor-set

Let

- $K \subseteq [0,1]$ be the Cantor set.
- $C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ be the ring of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
- $C(K,\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of continuous functions from $K$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Then, what can we say about the homomorphisms from $C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ to $C(K,\mathbb{R})$ ?

How many of them are injective ?

How many of them are surjective ?

Comment: Interesting question! I'd like to know about $C(K,\mathbb{R})$ in itself, starting with what the subspace topology looks like on $K$ in $[0,1]$

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question myself, but perhaps Chapter 10 (Homomorphisms and continuous mappings) from the book Rings of Continuous Functions by Gillman and Jerison might be useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gelfand Duality says that the category of Compact Hausdorff Spaces $\mathsf{CompHaus}$ is antiequivalent to the full subcategory of rings of the form $C(X)$ for a compact hausdorff space $X$, $\mathsf{C^*Alg}$. Everything I'm about to say is well treated in chapter IV.4 of Johnstone's *Stone Spaces*, and you can read more about it there.

This antiequivalence is witnessed by the functors

$X \mapsto CX$, and if $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous map, $Cf : CY \to CX$ is given by composition with $f$. So $(Cf)(\phi) = \phi \circ f$.

$R \mapsto \text{MaxSpec}(R) = \{ \text{maximal ideals of $R$} \}$, where we equip the space of maximal ideals with the Zariski Topology. If $f : R \to S$ is a ring hom (preserving $1$) then
$\text{MaxSpec}(f) : \text{MaxSpec}(S) \to \text{MaxSpec}(R)$ is given by $\mathfrak{m} \mapsto f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})$. It's not *immediately* obvious that the preimage of a maximal ideal in $S$ is maximal in $R$,
but it's true basically because $\mathbb{R}$ is finitely generated as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

Now, it takes some showing that (for compact hausdorff spaces $X$ and rings $R$ of the form $C(X)$ for some such $X$)

1. $\text{MaxSpec}(C(X)) \cong X$
2. $C(\text{MaxSpec}(R)) \cong R$
3. $\text{MaxSpec}(C(f)) "\cong" f$
4. $C(\text{MaxSpec}(f)) "\cong" f$

where by $"\cong"$, I mean that the map $\text{MaxSpec}(C(f))$ is equal to $f$ when we compose on either side with the relevant isomorphisms $\text{MaxSpec}(C(X)) \cong X$ and $Y \cong \text{MaxSpec}(C(Y))$.

---

Now. Why should we care? Well, this duality tells us that for compact hausdorff spaces $X$ and $Y$, we have a (natural) bijection

$$
\big \{ \text{Continuous Maps } f : X \to Y \big \}
\longleftrightarrow
\big \{ \text{Ring Homs } \tilde{f} : C(Y) \to C(X) \big \}
$$

So then we get to your question. What can we say about the ring homomorphisms $C[0,1] \to CK$?
They're in bijection with continuous maps $K \to [0,1]$!

Moreover, any "categorical" property of these arrows is preserved (but dualized). So for instance, a homomorphism from $C[0,1] \to CK$ is surjective if and only if it's an epimorphism (this is actually non-obvious. See the (well named) *Epimorphisms of C*-algebras are surjective* by Hofmann and Neeb).

Now since epis are dual to monos, this happens if and only if the corresponding map $K \to [0,1]$ is a monomorphism, which happens if and only if it's injective.

So surjections $C[0,1] \to CK$ are in natural bijection with (continuous) injections $K \to [0,1]$.

Of course, you can use this machinery to answer lots of questions of the type you're interested in.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish I could understand your solution but I have not yet undergone a course in topology as of yet. This question appeared in an entrance exam for admission to a masters program. So I feel there must be an elegant solution to this problem, only using the basic concepts of ring theory and metric spaces.

Comment: Rings of continuous functions on a topological space $X$ are necessarily linked to the topology of $X$ -- that's what makes them interesting! Moreover, the duality I've mentioned shows that we can identify a ring $CX$ with the (compact, hausdorff) space $X$ in a way that loses basically no information. So in this precise sense, studying rings of the form $CX$ _is_ studying the topology of compact hausdorff spaces. So there probably isn't a topology-free answer to your question (at least in this level of generality). But this shouldn't discourage you! There's a lot of great math left to learn!